# How to implement IEnumerable<T> interface?

Tags: c#

I took this code from a textbook and it does not compile and I'm completely stuck.

I feel like if you're an experienced C# user you will know the solution right away. Could you please take a quick look at it. Here's a link to [playground](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u2QNcW)

**Error**

```
CS0738: 'LinkedList<T>' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'LinkedList<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerator'
```

**Code**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
#nullable enable

public record LinkedListNode<T>(T Value)
{   
    public LinkedListNode<T>? Next { get; internal set; }
    public LinkedListNode<T>? Prev { get; internal set; }
    public override string? ToString() => Value?.ToString();
}


public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  public LinkedListNode<T>? First { get; private set; }
  public LinkedListNode<T>? Last { get; private set; }
  public LinkedListNode<T> AddLast(T node)
  {
    LinkedListNode<T> newNode = new(node);
    if (First is null || Last is null)
    {
      First = newNode;
      Last = First;
    }
    else
    {
      newNode.Prev = Last;
      Last.Next = newNode;
      Last = newNode;
    }
    return newNode;
  }
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    LinkedListNode<T>? current = First;
    while (current is not null)
    {
      yield return current.Value;
      current = current.Next;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need to implement the non-generic version of `IEnumerable`, usually simply like this: `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();` paste this line into your class, like on a new empty line above `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` and see if the error goes away (that's the entire line, don't add public or private or whatnot to it)

Comment: What Lasse said. Why do you need to do this? Backwards compatibility. Back in the old days when men lived in caves and we didn't have generics, there was the `IEnumerable` interface, similar to today's `IEnumerable<T>` interface - just without generics. `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`, and `IEnumerable` requires a `GetEnumerator` method which returns a non-generic `IEnumerable`. (BTW, is this still necessary in C# 9+, now that we have covariant return types?)

Comment: @Heinzi You had caves? All we had were a big rock we could sit under.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I did what you said and I get a new error `error CS0538: 'IEnumerable' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface`.

Comment: @manidos: You also need `using System.Collections;`, where the non-generic `IEnumerable` is defined.

Comment: @Heinzi, guys, you're the best! Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable` (non generic). So if you want to implement the first, you also have to implement the members of the second.

`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` must thus also be implemented - as the compiler hints.

However, this will not work:

```cs
public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // ... existing code

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Because from the compiler's point of view method by that name (and parameters) already exists. [Overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution) does not consider the return type of the method.

The solution is to implement the "ambigous" method using [explicitl interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

```cs
public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // ... existing code

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! It now makes perfect sense!